# How do I update the background color behind my office add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

How do I update the background color behind my office add-in?
This is an excel app and the color behind the app looks weird.. Can I somehow change it? I could no find anything on the web.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The task pane loads the web page specified in the manifest file (or the ribbon button to open). Depending on the web page content the background color is used. You may try to build a sample add-in with a task pane and play with background color properties, see [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator).

Also you may find the [Task panes in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/task-pane-add-ins) page helpful.